# React-Native How to create a picker where user can select multiple values same as data picker

Tags: react-native

[image]I am trying to build a picker where  user can select multiple item in a single picker.

Same as Date-Picker.Where user can select day , month and year in a single picker. But in my case value will be customised.
something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-multiple-picker)
.
But i am unable to link this library in my project due to some error. if you find similar solution or similar library Please help me.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution

Comment: can you post your `stack trace`, Your question not describing proper error detail

Comment: @HussainSherwani , I have added a screenshot .